# authentication failure when sending envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a DocuSign implementation that sends envelopes based on templates. For this I have to manually write my requests since our framework is incompatible with the provided Java SDK. Unfortunately, I am running into an error when actually attempting to send the envelope.

Our application impersonates another user since it will run on a server, the entire authentication flow seems to work (I got it working to the point where I have a JWT for the API)

In order to create a new envelope I use the following request body:

```
POST /v2.1/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/ HTTP/1.1
Host: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi
Authentication: Bearer eyJ0e.....
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "roleName": "Representative 1",
        "tabs": {
          "textTabs": [
            {
              "tabLabel": "testLabel",
              "value": "this is a pre-filled label"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "created",
  "templateId": "ba0ddc8e-648e-41f7-b4e5-56abf0073c8a"
}
```

I think this request is valid and complies with what I've found in the documentation. However, after sending it, I receive the following response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
    "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}
```

This makes me believe that I am using an incorrect integrator key, but I triple checked and the integrator key I am using matches the one I can see in the DocuSign admin panel.

What can I do to make this request work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting "An integrator key was not specified", then the issue is likely that DocuSign isn't seeing your `Authorization` header, or it's not able to interpret it correctly.

In looking at the headers of your call, it looks like you're incorrectly using `Authentication` when you should be using `Authorization`

Comment: I can perform the UserInfo call without any problems. all headers I'm sending are already present in the example in my question.

Comment: Sorry about that - totally missed the headers. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: oh my lord I can't believe I didn't notice the incorrect header.. I've been bashing my head against my desk over this for hours.. Thanks!